# How do I optimize The Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I ran a Pixel 3a on Android 13 Virtual Device on Android Studio and when the emulator is on it says "System Ui is not responding" I have Intel HAXM, How do I optimize android studio on my computer

Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 @ 1.10GHz
RAM: 4.00 GB (3.82 GB usable)
Windows 11 Home 64-bit
SSD

Comment: Just reboot the emulator (cold boot it).  That should fix the problem.  Its not about optimization at all.  Although really-  4 GB of RAM?  You're going to have a hard time getting Android Studio to run well on less than 16.  I didn't even know they made them that small anymore.

Comment: And the N4020 isn't going to win any contest either. Really, either debug on a real phone or get a new laptop, your device is way too underpowered to run emulators.